# Enumeration of polycube snakes

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics, combinatorial-geometry, discrete-geometry

Has anyone enumerated polycube snakes formed of $n$ cubes?
A polycube is an object created by gluing cubes face-to-face.
A polycube snake's dual graph is a path. I would be especially interested
if the snake's surface forms a manifold, i.e., there are not edge-edge
and vertex-vertex nonmanifold touchings. The closest I've found is this,
which analyzes a particular class ("partially directed") of snakes:

> Goupil, Alain, Marie-Eve Pellerin, and Jérôme de Wouters d’Oplinter. "Partially directed snake polyominoes." *Discrete Applied Mathematics* 236 (2018): 223-234.
>   [arXiv abs](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.8432)
>
> ---
>
> [image]
>   
>             
>   
>   <sup>Fig.7b</sup>

---

Comment: The two-dimensional problem has indeed been enumerated, but I'm not aware that the three-dimensional version has.

Answer (score 1):

This sequence doesn't seem to be in the OEIS yet! Perhaps someone with an account would like to add it.

Imagine standing at one end of the tunnel formed by a snake, and walking from one end to the other, recording each turn you make as you step from one cube to another; this maps the snake's shape to a string of $n-1$ letters (`S`traight, `L`eft, `R`ight, `U`p, `D`own). By standing initially facing from the first cube into the second, and with an appropriate rotation, you can always arrange it so that the first letter is `S` and the first non-`S` turn is a `R`ight turn.

I wrote a little C++ program to enumerate unique 3D *non-ouroboros* polycube snakes, both the "directed" version (where the snake's head is distinguishable from its tail) and the "undirected" version (where it's not). I'm not 100% sure that my program is correct, but the results seem plausible.

We might follow Gardner/Kim and consider `SRR` (the square-tetromino) or `SSRSRSR` (the O-octomino) to be *ouroboros* polycube snakes, whose head and tail are adjacent. (The 2x3 rectangle `SRRSR` is not a snake at all, because its head has 3 neighbors.) But an ouroboros can be represented by as many different letter-strings as it has cubes; e.g. `SSSSRSRSLRSRS` is not only the same as `SSLSLRSLSLSS` but also the same as `SSSRSRSLRSRSS` and `SSRSRSLRSRSSR` and so on. I've manually verified my program's enumeration of the 13 ten-cube ouroboroi.

| Cubes | Directed non-ouroboroi | Undirected non-ouroboroi | Undirected ouroboroi |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 2: `SS` `SR` | 2 |  |
| 4 | 6: `SSS` `SSR` `SRS` `SRL` `SRU` `SRD` | 5: `SSS` `SRS` `SRL` `SRU` `SRD` | 1: `SRR` |
| 5 | 23 | 16: `SSSS` `SSRS` `SRSS` `SRSR` `SRSL` `SRSU` `SRSD` `SRLS` `SRLR` `SRLD` `SRUS` `SRUL` `SRDS` `SRDR` `SRDL` `SRDU` |  |
| 6 | 93 | 54 | 1: `SRURU` |
| 7 | 386 | 212 |  |
| 8 | 1590 | 827 | 3: `SRSRSRS` `SRDRSRD` `SRDRSDR` |
| 9 | 6583 | 3369 |  |
| 10 | 27046 | 13653 | 13 |
| 11 | 111460 | 56052 |  |
| 12 | 456937 | 229004 | 122 |
| 13 | 1877277 | 939935 |  |
| 14 | 7683372 | 3843859 | 1115 |
| 15 | 31497124 | 15753903 |  |
| 16 | 128743825 | 64380796 | 12562 |
| 17 | 526907643 | 263475472 |  |
| 18 | 2151488689 | 1075780425 | 147350 |
| 19 | 8794145222 | 4397161320 |  |
| 20 | 35878493709 | 17939394036 | 1810165 |
| 21 | 146503034913 | 73251877235 |  |
| 22 | 597291499318 | 298646347226 | 22812552 |
| 23 | 2436903747928 | 1218453344740 |  |

OEIS A???: 1 1 2 6 23 93 386 1590 6583 27046 111460 456937 1877277 7683372 31497124 128743825 526907643 2151488689 8794145222 35878493709 146503034913 597291499318 2436903747928 ...

OEIS A???: 1 1 2 5 16 54 212 827 3369 13653 56052 229004 939935 3843859 15753903 64380796 263475472 1075780425 4397161320 17939394036 73251877235 298646347226 1218453344740 ...

OEIS A???: 1 1 2 6 16 55 212 830 3369 13666 56052 229126 939935 3844974 15753903 64393358 263475472 1075927775 4397161320 17941204201 73251877235 298669159778 1218453344740 ...

Comment: The second one is now https://oeis.org/A363201

Answer (score -1):

How about [OEIS A000162 Number of 3-dimensional polyominoes](http://oeis.org/search?q=polycube&sort=&language=&go=Search)?

--- rk